# ASP.NET Core : type enum as checkboxes in razor view, clicked according to int value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, enums

after realize that I am not able to really persist the checkboxes states by javascript(from differents machines), I was trying to make it work by server side.

What I am doing is with this enum:

```cs
namespace namespace
{
    [Flags]
    public enum prop: uint
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        a= 1,
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        b= 2,
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        c= 4
    }
}
```

And declared like this in the model:

```cs
public int prop
        {
            get { return prop; }
            set { prop= value; }
        }
```

Make it working as checkboxes, so if you click first and last then value will be send as 5 and so on.

> this is my controller:

```
public IActionResult action(int id)
        {

            var model = something

            model.class.class.Select(x => x.prop);

            return View(model);
        }
```

In my view I have printed as:

```cs
foreach(var a in Model)
    @Html.EditorFor(x = > a.prop)
```

This is the editor template:

```
@model Enum
@{
    var modelType = @Model.GetType();
}
@foreach (var name in Enum.GetNames(modelType))

{
    var value = Convert.ToInt32(Enum.Parse(modelType, name));

    if (value != 0)

    {

        var isChecked = ((Convert.ToInt32(Model) & value) == value) ? "checked" : null;

        <input type="checkbox" name="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix" value="@name"  class="prop" checked="@isChecked" data-valueCheck="@value" />
        @name
        <br />

    }

}
```

So How I can make by if I sent 7 to the server print the checkB. selected? . I already have done the js part so it always store the right value in the js object I send to the server, something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 00000000,
    "prop": 1,
    nestedobjectetc...
...
  }
]
```

So if I receive `"prop": 1`, then at least one checkbox should rendered as selected.

> So I am stacked and serching and trying things but not sure how to work with enums... some recomendations??
>   If it is not enough clear please let me know, thank you so much,
>   qiqke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own custom model binder to pass the `sum` of the selected checkbox values to your action when you submit the form.Refer to below demo:

1.MyModel.cs:

```
public class MyModel
{
    private int appliesOn;

    [BindProperty(BinderType = typeof(EnumToIntModelBinder))]
    public int AppliesOn
    {
        get { return appliesOn; }
        set { appliesOn = value; }
    }
}
```

2.EnumToIntModelBinder.cs

```
public class EnumToIntModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var value = valueProviderResult.Values;

        int sum = 0;

        foreach (var item in value)
        {
            sum += int.Parse(item);
        }

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(sum);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

3.Razor View:

```
<form asp-action="SumEnumCheckBox" method="post">
    <div class="checkboxContainer">

        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="myModel.AppliesOn" class="appliesOnField" id="" value="1" />@namespace.AppliesOn.Physical
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="myModel.AppliesOn" class="appliesOnField" id="" value="2" />@namespace.AppliesOn.Sendings
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="myModel.AppliesOn" class="appliesOnField" id="" value="4" />@namespace.AppliesOn.Billing
        </label>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

4.Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SumEnumCheckBox(MyModel myModel)
```

5.Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi @xing-zou , thank you very much. With this it will remember the checkboxes states? by js I can take the values with something like that : `$(this)[0].checked === true ? Number((result += valorAppliesOn) / 1) : (result -= this.value);` and send as a JSON object. The problem I have is I cannot remember if one check was clicked then wwhen it refresh it will be marked(according to the value). What do you think?

Comment: I mean, What I am trying is something like this : `var isChecked = ((Convert.ToInt32(Model) & value) == value) ? "checked" : null;` and them in the `input` have the `checked` attr like this: `checked="@isChecked`

Comment: @Qiqke I did not really understand what you were finding .My reply may misunderstand your requirement and it could not persist status.IMO, to persist checkboxes' status, you could use cookies from client side or [session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#set-and-get-session-values) from server side.You could save all selected values to asp.net core session and then populate them in get method.

Comment: Sorry, was my fault I explained myself really bad. I am going the reformulate my question, but basically what I am trying is if a get from server side appliesOn = 5 , then check  in the view when it is rendered the checkboxes with that values checked. Gonna change my answer

Comment: Ryan thanks a lot, your solution solved my problem perfecly!